# How can I set UNIX_TIMESTAMP correctly on my local?

Tags: mysql, sql, unix-timestamp

I have a table which has a column named `date_time`. It is containing a unix number of the time. Something like this:

```
// mytable
+----+------------+
| id | date_time  |
+----+------------+
| 1  | 1464499385 | -- 19 days ago
+----+------------+
--                     ^ these are based on current time which is 1464566088
```

Also here is my query:

```
SELECT id,
       (CASE WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time) >= CURDATE() THEN 'today'
             WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN 'yesteray'
             WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN 'in last week'
             ELSE 'in last month or more'
        END) as `range`
FROM mytable
WHERE 1;
```

---

The result of query above *on local* isn't the same as [*on fiddle*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9803/1).

on local: [image]

As you see the result on local is `yesterday` and on fiddle is `today`. Why there is a different and how can I fix it?

---

**Note:** when I select `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` on local and on fiddle, there is a different.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(); -- 1464566511 (on local)
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(); -- 1464562972 (on fiddle)
```

So how can I set identically?

Answer (score 2):

Sql fiddle server is in a different time zone.

Take 'UTC - your timezone' and subtract that many interval hours from your timestamp

You can convert with the difference using convert_tz :

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(datetime,'+00:00','-10:00');
```

[Convert _TZ MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) documents

You can Google time in UTC and take the difference or you can set global tinezone to your local [some support on that](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-upgrades.html)

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. +1